# How to set width and gap simultaneously in a bar chart? (Python, Plotly)

Tags: python, plotly, bar-chart

I know how to set the width of bars in a bar chart:

```py
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Bar(x = ['A', 'B', 'C'], y = [2, 4, 1], width=[0.5]*3)])
fig.update_layout(paper_bgcolor = 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',plot_bgcolor = 'rgba(0,0,0,0)')
fig.update_layout(bargap=0)
fig.show()
```

[image]

As you can see, the `bargap` is ignored. Because the width of bars has been set. Now, by removing the `width` property, we will get the following:

[image]

I desire by removing the gaps, have a thinner bar chart in the meanwhile.
Now, the **question** is:

> "How to set width and gap simultaneously in a bar chart through plotly in python?"

Answer (score 3):

There is a workaround. Check out the marimekko example at https://plotly.com/python/bar-charts/

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

labels = ['A', 'B', 'C']
widths = np.array([0.5]*3)
widths[1] = 0.5*4

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Bar(x=np.cumsum(widths)-widths, width=widths, offset=0, y = [2, 4, 1])])
fig.update_layout(paper_bgcolor = 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',plot_bgcolor = 'rgba(0,0,0,0)')
fig.update_xaxes( 
    showline = True, linecolor = '#000',
    tickvals=np.cumsum(widths)-widths/2, 
    ticktext= ["%s" % (l) for l, w in zip(labels, widths)]
)
fig.update_yaxes( 
    showline = True, linecolor = '#000')
fig.update_layout()
fig.show()
```

[image: Output]